# Double quote in title breaks Tweet button.

Tags: bug, status-completed, twitter

This [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7430/3190) has a double quote in the title which causes the Twitter pop-up to throw an error. Once I removed the quotation marks it worked just fine.

[image]

Comment: hmm, this is correctly URL encoded to %22custom%22 = `"custom"`

Comment: The url I'm getting when I click the tweet button: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Stack+Exchange+Android+Enthusiasts+Q%3A+How+is+Android+more+%22custom%22+than+iOS%3F&url=http%3A%2F%2Fandroid.stackexchange.com%2Fq%2F7430%2F3190

Maybe it is a chrome issue: http://imgur.com/2oI5p

Comment: Not a Chrome issue. I'm also seeing it with Firefox 4

Comment: Changed them to single quotes and it works fine.

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Twitter is broken - even their own tweet button builder won't work with text that contains a quote.  http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

Comment: Yep, I've been having to manually HTML-ize special characters.